# Another word for 'said proudly'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Consider this sentence:

> "My handwriting is very good" said Smith proudly

I want to replace "said Smith proudly" with something that will appear a bit more professional or polished but with the meaning unchanged. What could that be...?

Comment: Confidently? not proud for sure but it works,

Comment: Thanks @Grizzly. But the word or phrase has to be `proud` or closely related to it...:)

Comment: Smith ***beamed***

Comment: I doubt @Jim...:) The person is actually proud..so something related to that I'm looking at..

Comment: @user308123 - uhhm... Ok.   Have you looked up *beam*??

Comment: yes @Jim. Different meanings are suggested in a google search..

Comment: As stated the question is POB. There can be no definitive answer to what “appears a bit more professional and polished.”

Comment: You say you don't want to use *said Smith proudly*, yet you reject all suggestions that aren't *proud*. Either your question is misleading and you specifically only want a different word for *said* (in which case, you should amend what you say you want replaced), or there is something else you're trying to express that isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a neutral word, I would use **proclaim**:

> to declare publicly, typically insistently, proudly, or defiantly and in either speech or writing
>   <sub>[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proclaim#synonyms)</sub>

Otherwise you have [**brag**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brag) and its synonyms, which are negative.

Comment: Actually @Laurel the sentence is not `"My handwriting is very good"`. I just mentioned it to convey an idea.What I actually have is a set of lines a person is saying to another person. And the first person is in fact quite proud of all that he is stating (hence I wanted something that would mean proud..like for eg. `expressed with pride` or maybe some other phrase that would give an impression to the reader that the idea conveyed is intending `proud` or `pride`). I thought of `expressed with pride` but then `expressed` sounded a bit off..can I replace `expressed` with some other suitable word?

Comment: @user308123 *Proclaim* ***is*** another word for *said* and *expressed*: *proclaimed with pride*. If it's not suitable, you need to explain why it's not suitable. (And explain why *expressed* is "a bit off.")

Comment: @JasonBassford The word has nothing to do with pride. It is sometimes used in association with pride, but that's just about it.

Answer (score 0):

***[boast](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boast)***

"My handwriting is very good" **boasted** Smith.

> *[reporting verb]* Talk with excessive pride and self-satisfaction about one's achievements, possessions, or abilities.
>   *[no object] ‘she boasted about her many conquests’*

*syn:*

> brag, crow, swagger, swank, gloat, show off, blow one's own trumpet, sing one's own praises, congratulate oneself, pat oneself on the back; exaggerate, overstate;
>   preen oneself, give oneself airs;
>   informaltalk big, blow hard, lay it on thick, shoot one's mouth off;
>   informalskite, big-note oneself